# awk for loop on files in directory

Tags: awk, files

How could I loop through each file in a directory using this awk command?

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a{print $1 FS a[$2]}' email.phone.txt username.email.txt
```

Basically this partially matches columns and outputs the results in a combined fashion.

Example of this would be >

email.phone.txt - contains:

```
email@email.com:phoneexample
```

username.email.txt - contains:

```
user1:email@email.com
user131:email@email.com
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT - should be:

```
user1:phoneexample
user131:phoneexample
```

but this only works on 1 text file being

```
email.phone.txt
```

however I have multiple files with the same content in a subdirectory, example:

```
../lists/
email.phone1.txt
email.phone2.txt
email.phone3.txt
....
```

and it would be quite time consuming to individually awk each file, is it possible I could use a for loop for each file in directory and output example >

```
result1.txt
result2.txt
result3.txt
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to run that awk script for each `email.phone*.txt` file, with the same `username.email.txt`? Something like this should do. The tail part (`1.txt`, etc.) of the output filename is taken from the input filename.

```
for f in email.phone*.txt; do
    out="result${f#email.phone}"       # remove leading 'email.phone'
    awk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a{print $1 FS a[$2]}' \
        "$f" username.email.txt > "$out"
done
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot :) and accept answer once tested.